# How to send base64 data to Nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, body-parser, html2pdf

I have a base64 version of pdf on my client side. I want to send it to the Nodejs server. I have the base64 on a variable like this

```
newpdf=btoa(pdf);
console.log(newpdf)
```

This statement logs the base64 on my google console

However when I send the `newpdf` to the server and access it via `req.body.newpdf` it returns undefined.

From stackoverflow I found out that you can send data using ajax request so I did this

```
 $.post('./setup', newpdf, function(result) {
                console.log('result', result);
                 console.log(typeof encodedpdf);
});
```

On my google console I get

```
result {success: true}
string
```

In the server on the post route

```
app.post('/setup', function(req, res, next) {
    var encodedpdf=(req.body.newpdf)
    console.log(encodedpdf);

    console.log(typeof encodedpdf);
})
```

This returns `undefined` `undefined`.

I have tried a lot of things but I just cannot get the base64 at the server. I don't know if this is because of my body-parser setup

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '5mb',
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    extended: false 
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '5mb'
}))
```

Comment: What does console.log(req.body) show?

Comment: req.body shows a very long string of some type looking like this

Ft7oUlsjJD7XGR824klKIlp2UW57H2j OWVZrt4N5DdtKmKuBmnKp7NcVAbOYiIpZOKjk9w8ZNGtKVGgj4TURHtuQllNBKPknGmmfAOq jVvEFGr1mws nRodlTn0wqORVVmlpWmSvm1pjw flrdeVwKSSTWfCe w/lhyLig8rBh2l3FWMLomTcb3NE

Comment: typeof req.body shows object

Comment: I does not match the base64 that is getting console logged on the browser. Also typeof encodedpdf on the browser returns string

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is that `$.post` expects JSON as a body (by default) but you're sending a string. Try sending `{payload: newpdf}` instead of `newpdf` as body. Then on the server the contents of `newpdf` will be available under `req.body.payload`

Comment: OMG thank you so much. You saved my life. I have spend a lot of hours in this problem

Comment: Will will add your reply at the answer section so that I can approve your answer?